# Unknown host exception while connecting with Ejabberd Server hosted on server machine from Android API

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am using SMACK API 4.1.4 for communicating with Ejabberd server for chatting from my Android app. 
My Ejabberd server is hosted over domain name i.e:- "dev.oodlesvdct.in".
I am getting **Unknown host exception** while calling the connect method of smack API.

Putting DOMAIN-"dev.oodlesvdct.in" and HOST - "dev.oodlesvdct.in".

But as i install XMPP client i.e **Pidgin** that works fine for me on the same server.
**

> Is there any configuration i am missing at server side or this is an
>   issue due to SMACK API methods.

**

Would appreciate if you please help me regarding this issue.

> Connection closed with error
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException:
>   host-unknown You can read more about the meaning of this stream error
>   at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions
>    at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1003)
>   at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:944)
>   at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:959)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks